# view controller may not respond to 'activatetab'

Tags: iphone, xcode

everything works fine but I can't find anything about two warnings I am receiving. here is one of them.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);

[self activateTab:item.tag];   //<------viewcontroller may not respond to activateTab 
}

- (void)activateTab:(int)index {
switch (index) {
    case 1:{
```

in debugger it says

messages without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '...' as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the method `activateTab:` in your header file too.

Comment: Or put it above tabBar:didSelectItem